# Does fighting type pokemon with water moves have advantage on normal type pokemon?

Tags: pokemon-go

I play pokemon go and want a pokemon that have advantage on snorlax and I can evolve to a poliwrath. And poliwrath is a water/fighting type but have most water moves. Does the water moves have advantage on normal type pokemon or is it just the types water is effective on?

If it doesn't, do you have any other tips witch pokemon I should use aganist snorlax?

Comment: A fighting type move would be good against it. Being fighting type doesn't make a difference if it's a water type move.

Answer (score 2):

As Vemonus suggested, it's only the *move* type that makes a difference. The Pokemon type determines what a Pokemon is *weak* against.

So if your Poliwrath has a move like "Submission" (Fighting type move) then yes, that will have a bonus on Normal types.

Comment: That's what I said... :P

Comment: I saw nothing...

Comment: Ok, thanks. Do you have any tips which pokemon I should use, beacuse, poliwrath only have one fighting move.

Comment: @JoelÄng Unfortunately most fighting-types in Go aren't very good, so your best bet is just a snorlax, vaporeon, lapras, or dragonite of your own

Comment: Poliwrath is one of the few Pokemon that has fighting moves that doesn't have a weakness against earthquake. So it's either that, or follow Pyritie's advice